# closure of domain is compact implies finitely many holes in the domain

Tags: complex-analysis

In many complex analysis theorems, we make the assumption that the closure of the domain $\bar{\Omega}$ is compact. Does that mean that the domain can only contain finitely many holes? I was thinking this must be true, since the boundary is closed and bounded, so it must also be compact, and if we have infinitely many holes we cannot find a finite subcover.

Comment: How do you define domain?

Answer (score 2):

No. Take$$\Omega=D(0,2)\setminus\left(\{0\}\cup\overline{D\left(1,\frac18\right)}\cup\overline{ D\left(\frac12,\frac1{16}\right)}\cup\overline{D\left(\frac14,\frac1{32}\right)}\cup\ldots\right).$$Then $\Omega$ is open and connected, but $\overline\Omega^\complement$ has infinitely many connected components.